# Dataloader MISSING_ARGUMENT on upsert

Tags: data-loader

I have a csv file with Account records, that I'm trying to upsert with command line dataloader.
Specifying external Id field (in my case it's Load_Id__c)

my mapping file doesn't have any other relationship fields.

But I keep getting the MISSING_ARGUMENT error
Error message:Load_Id__c not specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve such error you should check very carefully the case of field names in your mapping and configuration files!
The case of destination field names must be the same as in the destination org.

In my case I had Load_I**D**__c instead of Load_I**d**__c (as in the destination org) in the configuration file.